# Designing in-page help. Alternatives to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a website to have a help area in each page. This help area will show information about the page opened but you will be able to browse the help to find information related to some other pages.

The only way I see to achieve this is to use an *iframe*. Is there any other alternative method?

Is it a good idea? Do you know any better design alternative to the help area that I have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe is easy to use but it's an old way an alternative solution is to use ajax to change the content of the help section.

Comment: But to be an old way is not necessarily a bad thing. Is there any advantage using ajax over iframes?

Comment: if this will be a privet area (require username and password) it's ok to use an iframes 
but if it's a public area google can index the help page alone and show it in the search result with out the rest of the page  and one last point if the user get the url of the help page he can open it also with out the rest of the page but in ajax you don't have this problem